# Vector with too short arrow

Tags: math-mode, amsmath, vector

I'm trying to write two vectors like this:

[image]

Currently I'm using `$\vec{p_e,\SI{10}{\hertz},s2}$` bug ig looks like this:

[image]

**How can I write it correctly?**

That means:

- long vector arrow
- italic Hz

Comment: Why not `\vec{p}_{e,\SI{10}{\hertz},s2}`? You can use `\overrightarrow` to get that exact output, but, at least to me, the arrow is too big.

Comment: Yeah these are quite long but its the only part in my thesis so its ok. How do I get the italic units?

Comment: @Hedge The units should always be upright.

Comment: The standard says that units should be typeset upright, I don't see a reason to get the italic version (apart from the fact that that's not italic but math normal font, in the first image).

Comment: 1) from my perspective (and at least in line with german regulations) the units are UNITS and therefore should NOT be italicized 2) Just write Hz instead of \hertz.. "the challenge" is to get it regular

Comment: Ok ok, you've won :D @Bort How did you know I'm German?

Comment: (it is part of your profile) honestly: I did not, I am and thus that are the rules I am familiar with. Some conventions differ (see e.g. the shape of the integral sign)

Answer (score 6):

As far I have understood the math in the question, the vector is *p*, the remaining part is just an index to the vector. Therefore, a short vector would be sufficient as shown in the following example. I do not know about `e`, `s2`, and `d7`, but `10 Hz` is clearly a number with unit, typeset upright, as already shown in the question and correctly done via `\SI{10}{\hertz}` with the macro `\SI` from package `siunitx`.

`\vec{p}` is replaced by `\vec{{}p}` as Manuel has suggested in his [comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/261552/vector-with-too-short-arrow/261555?noredirect=1#comment627363_261555).

The example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}

\begin{document}
  \dots ors $\vec{{}p}_{e,\SI{10}{\hertz},s2}$
  respectively $\vec{{}p}_{e,\SI{10}{\hertz},d7}$
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: This is a place where `\vec{\kern0pt p}` or `\vec{{}p}` is beneficial, in my opinion.

Comment: @Manuel Thanks, it indeed looks better. Answer updated.

Answer (score 5):

You might want to give a try to the `esvect`  package, which has `8` nice arrow shapes, longer than the arrow that comes with `vec`. The base command is `\vv`, and there is a `\vv*` command for vectors with indices, in order to have a correct spacing between vector and index:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage[e]{esvect}

\begin{document}

  \dots ors $\vv*{p}{e,\SI{10}{\hertz},s2}$
  respectively $\vv*{p}{e,\SI{10}{\hertz},d7}$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `\overrightarrow`, it looks like
`$\overrightarrow{p_{e,\SI{10}{\hertz},d7}}$`

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Using old-arrows package with arrows very closer to the initial image.

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb}
\usepackage{old-arrows}

\begin{document}
$\overrightarrow{ p_{\scriptstyle e,10 Hz,s2}}$ respectively $\overrightarrow{ p_{\scriptstyle e,10 Hz,d7}}$
\end{document}
```