# How can I increase the length of the vector sign to be almost equal to the argument?

Tags: math-mode, vector

The standard LaTeX vector looks fine over the lowercase arguments, but too short over the uppercase and multi-letter arguments:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
    \begin{math}
    \\
    \vec{v}\\
    \vec{V}\\
    \vec{AC}\\
    \vec{ABCD}
    \end{math}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Is there any way to make it longer, depending on the argument used?

I'd love it to stretch from above the vertex of A to above the serif of C in the last example (but nothing as drastic as `\overrightarrow{A_1C_2}`.

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114321/extensible-vec-instead-of-overrightarrow

Comment: It's almost a duplicate question, altough I would like to give it another chance, to see if a more plain TeX, more robust, and more complete approach appears. I might give a bounty on that question to revive it.

Comment: Related: [Vector with too short arrow](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/261552/5764)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `esvect` package has very nice vector arrows, with 8 different arrow tips:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{array}%
\usepackage{esvect}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{array}{ll}
        \vec{v}&  \vv{v}  \\
    \vec{V} &  \vv{V}\\
    \vec{AC} &   \vv{AB}\\
    \vec{ABCD} &  \vv{ABCD}
    \end{array} \]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: But aren't those arrows just a bit too excessive? Overbearing?

Comment: I don't think so, but if you finf it's a little too long on the left side, say, you can   write a macro such as, say: `\newcommand\myvv[1]{\mkern1.5mu\vv{\mkern-1.5mu#1}}`.

Answer (score 1):

I really like the `esvect` package.  If you read the documentation (https://www.ctan.org/pkg/esvect), it tells you that you can select the type of arrow that you want.  The default option is

```
\usepackage[d]{esvect}
```

Although you don't need to add the "d".  If you select option "h", then the arrow looks a little more like the one used in `\vec`.